# Image get stored in internal storage while sharing images in android

Tags: android, share, android-sharing, share-intent

Im creating on application in that application am sharing layout like image. while am sharing am converting layout into image and sharing in social network, but issues is image getting stored in internal storage, how to delete after sharing an image.

```
 bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(itemView.getWidth(), itemView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            itemView.draw(canvas);
            try {
                // output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/file.png");
                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                image_path = file.getAbsolutePath();


                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, out);
                out.close();

                bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                sharePost();


  public void sharePost() {
    try {
        Resources resources = context1.getResources();
        final String photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                context1.getContentResolver(), image_path, null, null);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
        emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        emailIntent.setType("image/*");

        PackageManager pm = context1.getPackageManager();

        Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share via Oddcast");

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
            // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
            ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
            String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (packageName.contains("android.email")) {
                emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            } else {
                emailIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
                if (packageName.contains("twitter")) {

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                } else if (packageName.contains("facebook")) {
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);

                } else if (packageName.contains("mms")) {

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                } else if (packageName.contains("android.gm")) {

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                } else if (packageName.contains("whatsapp")) {

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                }else if (packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.plus")) {

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(photoUri));
                }
                else{

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, MyCustomAdapter.bmpUri);
                }

                intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(emailIntent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
            }
        }

        // convert intentList to array
        LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);

        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
        context1.startActivity(openInChooser);
        Log.e("start", "start");

    }catch (SecurityException e) {

        Toast.makeText(context1, "Please check your permissions settings.Permission issue.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }  catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(context1, "Please check your permissions settings.Permission issue.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    file.delete();
    Log.e("emd","end");
    //context1.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(bmpUri)))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of startActivity try to call startActivityForResult. Overide the onActivityResult method and delete the image file you created